# Python Verifying if input is int and greater than 0

Tags: python

So I need to ask the client to enter the variable again if it is not integer or is less or equal to 0. I can not let it get an program error and end it.

```
def enter_amount():


amount=input("Enter amount:")
while (not isinstance(amount, int)) or amount<=0:
    amount=input("The amount can't be negative, please try again:")
return amount
```

Tried this, and it always fails the test. If you have any ideas I would be grateful.

Comment: Is this python 2.x or 3.x? in 2.x, _input_ evaluates user input to a python expression and is usually a bad choice while _raw_input_ gives you a string. In 3.x, _input_ gives you a string, not an int.

Comment: "Didn't work." Great, awesome, ***HOW.***

Comment: It is python 3.x. Ook, then how do I check both of this and retry if not met? If it input is string no matter what the user writes, then that isinstance is pretty much useless in this situation.

Comment: @NestorCristian in Python3, `input()` will never be an int, so `isinstance(amount, int)` will always fail.

Comment: @AdamSmith I realized that a few seconds ago, but now I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert input to an integer and then check that value. Since the user may input garbage, you have to handle the integer conversion by catching a value exception.

```
def get_amount():
    while True:
        amount = input("Enter amount: ")
        try:
            val = int(amount)
            if val >= 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount can't be negative, try again")
        except ValueError:
            print("Amount must be a number, try again")
    return val
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use return outside of a function! Wrap your code in a function and it should be fine.

```
def test():
    amount=input("Enter amount:")
    while (not isinstance(amount, int)) or amount<=0:
        amount=input("The amount can't be negative, please try again:")
    print(amount)
    return amount

test()
```

Comment: It was in a function, forgot to put it there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getUserAmount():
    while True:
        amount = input("Enter amount: ")
        try:
            value = int(amount)
            if value >= 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount is negative, try again")
        except ValueError:
            print("Amount must be a number, try again")

    return value

main()
```