# How to validate input from user within a function? #python3

Tags: python-3.6

Write a function that receives an integer from the user and validates that it’s larger than 10. If not, ask for it again.

My solution:

def func():

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number larger than 10: "))
while num < 10:
    print("Please enter a number LARGER than 10")
if num > 10:
    print("Thank you!")

    func()
```

what am I doing wrong? Thanks! I want to use a loop and ask the user twice or thank you if > 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Verifying if input is int and greater than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112377/python-verifying-if-input-is-int-and-greater-than-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use while else statement:

```
def func():
    num = int(input("Please enter a number larger than 10: "))
    while num <= 10:
        func()
    else:
        print("Thank you!")
        exit() # or some other stuff


func()
```

Comment: Thanks! this one really helped! However, I had to delete the second message "LARGER than 10" for it to not be displayed twice.

Comment: Yep. Changed too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
def get_input():
    num = int(input("Please enter a number larger than 10: "))
    return(num)

while get_input() <= 10:
    print("wrong input")

print("Thank you!")
```

The `while` loop will call the `get_input` method and evaluate whether the number is valid or not. Depending on the outcome, it will either print a warning and call the method again, or end the while loop and continue.